# What ever happened to Launch?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

Launch is famous, as we all know, for being a character who disappeared because Akira Toriyama forgot about her.

In the manga Launch disappears as a character but in the anime she at least has a few appearances in DBZ and made a cameo in the Majin Buu saga.

But I just do not know what became of her. What happened to her?

Comment: http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Launch

Comment: After the Majin Buu saga?

Comment: If your lucky hell bring her back in db super

Comment: the author quite literally forgot about her

Answer (score 3):

After the events of dragonball, Launch stayed with Tien and Chiaotzu (despite Tien's objections) and can be seen in the saiyan saga with them and is seen at a bar drinking after Tien's death. After the Saiyan saga though she is sort of written out. We know from some filler that she is in one of the cities and offers up her energy for Goku's spirit bomb but there's not a lot else.

She fell in love with Tien at first sight but he gave her the cold shoulder focusing instead on his farming work but it is possible that they got together and she is living with him as she has been pursuing him for some time.

[Pretty much everything I mentioned is here](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Launch#cite_note-8)

Comment: Get some pictures from the show and reference the episode numbers instead of the wiki. You will be rewarded.